# How to convert .s to .asm?

Tags: assembly, gcc, gnu-assembler

So I was having fun with MikeOS but I suck at Assembly. So I wrote a program in C, and convert it to Assembly with GCC(IN Ubuntu). But when I convert it, it ends up as a .s file. So how do I convert this to .asm? The command I used to make the .s file is;

```
gcc -S test.c
```

So another way to do this is, how do I convert .s to .bin? That might help as well.

Thanks!

Comment: .s is assembly too...

Comment: Yes, but .asm is Intel, .s is something different. (I might be wrong, I am new to Assembly)

Comment: Please see my answer...

Comment: @ArenCoskun There are dozens of assemblers using the file extension `.asm`.  Without knowing what assembler you want, this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2):

No conversion is needed. The `.s` extension is for assembly, just as `.asm`.
Just two different extensions for the same language.

You may rename the file if you want to use `.asm`.

But keep in mind that assembly produced by a compiler such as GCC is very unlikely to be used directly in a freestanding environment such as a custom OS, as it will rely on stuff available in GCC and on your host system.

If you're looking to generate ASM into different dialects, take a look at the GCC flags, like `-masm`:

- `-masm=intel` Intel syntax
- `-masm=att` AT&T syntax

**EDIT**

As mentioned by Peter Cordes, the convention is usually to use `.s` for AT&T syntax and `.asm` for Intel.
Note that GCC will still generate a `.s` file with Intel syntax, though...

Comment: Asm that can be assembled by GCC (i.e. in GAS AT&T syntax or `.intel_syntax noprefix` from `-masm=intel`) should definitely be in a `.S` (C preprocessor + assemble) or `.s` (just assemble) file.  I mean sure you can call it `.asm`, but you could also call your C source file `hello.foobar` and have to manually tell `gcc` what kind of file it was with `-x` options.  By convention, `.asm` is typically used for NASM source files, not GAS.  (A different flavour of Intel syntax)

Comment: @PeterCordes By convention yes, although GCC doesn't care and generate .s files regardless of the syntax...

Comment: That's not what I said.  GCC can't generate NASM syntax files.  NASM uses different directives like `db "foo", 0` instead of `.asciz "foo"`, and `mov edi, symbol` is a mov-immediate, not a load.  So it's not like GAS `.intel_syntax`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info for more about the different flavours of Intel syntax.  GAS can assemble `.s` files from `gcc -S -masm=intel`, NASM can't.